# VS2013 - static const already defined

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I have the following code (simplified), which compiles fine in gcc, but gives an error in VS:

```
// main.cpp
#include "test.h"
int main() {
  return 0;
}

// test.h
#pragma once
class Test {
  static const int TEST = 3;
};

// test.cpp
#include "test.h"
const int Test::TEST;
```

Error:

```
main.obj : error LNK2005: "private: static int const Test::TEST" (?TEST@Test@@0HB) already defined in test.obj
```

Is it a VS bug or is gcc incorrectly allowing me to define the static const member explicitly?

**Update:** found this in the [C++ Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf) (9.4.2.3):

> If a non-volatile const static data member is of integral or enumeration type, its declaration in the class
>   definition can specify a brace-or-equal-initializer in which every initializer-clause that is an assignment-expression is a constant expression (5.20). A static data member of literal type can be declared in the
>   class definition with the constexpr specifier; if so, its declaration shall specify a brace-or-equal-initializer
>   in which every initializer-clause that is an assignment-expression is a constant expression. [ Note: In both
>   these cases, the member may appear in constant expressions. — end note ] *The member shall still be defined
>   in a namespace scope if it is odr-used (3.2) in the program and the namespace scope definition shall not
>   contain an initializer.*

**Update #2:** found a [bug report](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedbackdetail/view/933699/lnk2005-when-defining-static-const-member), which claims that it is fixed in the *next major version*.

Comment: What if you remove `const int Test::TEST;` from your `test.cpp`, will gcc compile the code?

Comment: It seems to work, but I'm working with code that explicitly defines those lines and don't want to edit it as it will break again on the next svn update.

Comment: Thanks, I just wanted to know if gcc has a bug of a different kind. I thought it requires you to define the constant explicitly in all cases. But if it doesn't then there is a bug in MSVC only.

Comment: On a side note, I'd use an enum here, which would conveniently avoid this bug as well.

Answer (score 5):

Exactly as you said it was a MSVC [bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedbackdetail/view/933699/lnk2005-when-defining-static-const-member).
The code compiles and runs perfectly in Visual Studio 2015 RC with default project options.

[image]

The compiler thinks "static const int TEST = 3;" and "const int Test::TEST;" are two different definitions of the same variable. To fix this in your version you could try setting the static variable value in the .cpp file:

```
// test.h
#pragma once
class Test {
  static const int TEST;
};

// test.cpp
#include "test.h"
const int Test::TEST = 3;
```

Answer (score 1):

With [Microsoft Extensions to C and C++](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/34h23df8(v=vs.71).aspx) enabled, compiler generates the out-of-class definition automatically. Some compiler versions are probably buggy and do this auto-definition even when you defined it manually (e.g. when writing portable code).

You can either disable the extensions, or check for _MSC_EXTENSIONS macro. It's defined when the /Ze option is set. For example:

```
#ifndef _MSC_EXTENSIONS
   const int MyClass::MyStaticMember;
#endif
```